# Why is my bedroom light not working?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I'm after some advice please.  This afternoon I was replacing a ceiling light fitting with a pendant fitting in my boys new bedroom.  Put the bulb in and no power.  Checked the bulb and it works, checked the wiring all correct.  Still not working.  Replaced the new fitting for the old one and still no power.  Noticed that on the switch board there are 2 breakers for the lights.  One breaker work, the other doesn't.  All the light on this breaker are off, this breaker also controls my boys bedroom.  Do I have a problem with the breaker or is it something else?

Comment: Have you rechecked your wire connections? It worked before I assume.

Comment: How exactly is the breaker not working, does it immediately trip when you turn it on? How did you verify that the wiring is right?